# app.config visual studio creation

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio-2010, app-config

A simple question, where I have perhaps just overlooked the obvious.

I am trying to use ApplicationSettings in C++ (.NET) using Visual Studio 2010 Express (I also use 2008 pro)

However I can get nowhere with this - if I try to use the form designer to add a setting i get "No settings file exists in project. Add a settings file and try again". How do I add a setting file (app.config)? There is no option in any of the "add" sections.  I have tried adding a file manually both from within VS (create a new file and save) and from Explorer.

Before I crack and just write some code to read an XML config file - please can someone explain the correct way to setup and use app.config - just, for example, to save the location and size of the main form.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a managed C++ project?

A settings file is based on .Net's `ApplicationSettingsBase` and `ConfigurationManager` classes, so unless you're using .Net you won't be able to use them easily.

EDIT: I've just created a managed C++ project, and you're right, there is no option to add a settings file.

In a C# project this produces a static class derived from `ApplicationSettingsBase`, which Visual Studio updates automatically from a GUI based configuration screen. I can only assume that there is no support for auto generation of a managed C++ class instead. Sorry.

Comment: Yes - using .net.  I did try deriving a class from ApplicationSettingsBase - as per a msdn article but still no joy.

Comment: I guess it's time to roll my own - having spent enough hours looking at this! However, there does seem to be some support - Data. applicationsettings in the properties tab of the designer.

Comment: To answer my own question - and pose another. 
The way to do this, seems to be to create a class inheriting from ApplicatioSettingsBase - the sample code in msdn for ApplicationSettingsBase works well.  However given that VS 2012 has a create config file option:  is there an easier way to do this and automate the linking of properties to the config file?  

Maybe it's just laziness on my part - but the ApplicationSettings section of the properties tab implies that there is a way to do this (if not in VS2010 then in 2012)